# Expected value of dependent matrix product

Tags: matrices, expected-value, covariance

Assume the matrix product term $AXBYC$ where each one is an $n\times n$ matrix. $A, B, C$ are constant, but $X, Y$ are variable and are **not** independent from one another, hence their covariance is not zero. We know that to calculate the expected value of two random matrices $V, W$ where there are dependent, we have:

$$E[VW]=E[V]E[W]+cov[V,W]$$

My question is how we would get the expectation in this case. I am not sure about the $cov$ part mainly. How would the constants play a part? Can we write $cov(AXB, YC)$ or $cov(AX, BYC)$? Are these different and if so how would we break it down?

$$E[AXBYC]=AE[X]BE[Y]C + ?$$

Comment: How are you defining covariance between random matrices? Unless you vectorize them, it would be a tensor in general.

Comment: How would it look like if we vectorize it by column? @Golden_Ratio

Comment: It would be the usual [cross-covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-covariance_matrix) but applied to $vec(V),vec(W)$

Comment: See also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203299/covariance-between-two-random-matrices)

Comment: The cross-cov matrix looks like what I need, but if I only know that the columns of $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed with a known mean and covariance matrix, can I get the cross-cov matrix between (1) columns of $X$ itself, (2) one column of $X$ with another column from $Y$? @Golden_Ratio

Comment: You'll need some info on the joint distribution between columns for that

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do better than observing that the entry $(i,\ell)$ of $E(XBY)$ is
$$\sum_{jk}b_{jk}E(X_{ij}Y_{k\ell}),$$